# How to get rgb color from 1 pixel from a bitmap

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Before jumping straight to the duplicate button, please read this!

So I have been searched now for 5 hours and still didn't figure it out how to get the rgb color from 1, yes, only 1 pixel of a bitmap. The bitmap in my situation is a circle that first rotates and then my program should determine which rgb color the pixel has at (bitmap.width()/2 , around 15).

I'd really appreciate some help!

Comment: What class is your data stored in? If it's android's `Bitmap`, then your answer is [in the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getPixel%28int,%20int%29).

Comment: woah those dislikes... nice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

So for the people who would have the same problem... Basically when you use an **ImageView** and make an **Animation** with it, Android just makes a *copy* of the ImageView. So everytime I spinned the wheel, he took the same coordinates relative to the position it was initially in. Hope I helped some other people!

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** This answer does not work on Android, at the time of writing it, it was not clear Android is the target platform. I'll keep the answer because it may be of use to others nevertheless.

When the bitmap is available as a [`java.awt.image.BufferedImage`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) you can use the method [`getRGB(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getRGB-int-int-). To create a `BufferedImage` you can use [`javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(File)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read-java.io.File-).

The class [`java.awt.Color`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html) can help you interpreting the returned `int` value: Pass the value to the [constructor taking a single `int`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color-int-) and use the methods [`getRed()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#getRed--), [`getGreen()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#getGreen--) and [`getBlue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#getBlue--).

Comment: Thanks for you reply! I hoped it would work but Android Studio doesn't see the class BufferedImage... Oh and I cleaned the project, still nothing. Have a look: http://prntscr.com/bl0n3d

Comment: @Spycer0, the only tag on your question was `java`, so I thought you have the whole Java API available. It is an important information that you are developing for Android, please add this to your question (use the _edit_ button below it). Also please add the code you already have (as text, not as screenshot). See the StackOverflow help page [for formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and [asking in general](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information.